# Windows authetication working only for curent user and not for all domain users

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

I am working on mvc3 project and using windows authentication for authentication purpose.
It is working on my credentials but when I try to login different user with same domain it is not working.
Below is setting in my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
 <authorization>
  <allow roles="domainname\Domain Users" />
  <allow users="domainname\username" />
  <!--<deny users="*" />-->

   <!--<deny users="?"></deny>-->
</authorization>
 <appSettings>
     <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
     <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

and in IIS Server I am setting windows authentication = enabled and anonymous authentication = disabled

What am I missing or doing wrong? Please help

Comment: What will happen if you keep only  <allow roles="domainname\Domain Users" /> and remove other allow.

Comment: I tried first with that one only :).. But since it was not working added <allow users="domainname\username" />

Comment: <allow roles="Domain Users" />

Comment: thanks... but not working :(

Comment: I suggest use any group except Domain Users. See does it work ?

Comment: Got it working :)..What I did was to right click on project name and select 'Use IIS server' ..This allowed me to set properties for my project which was not available earlier.. Here I set Windows Authentication = Enabled.. That did the trick